# Jasper Reports virtualizer - alternative for large amounts of data

Tags: memory, jasper-reports, large-data

Jasper-reports has a virtualizer option that writes to disk but I'm curious if there is another way to handle large amounts of data that cause out of memory problems.

- Does the gzip virtualizer work well instead of file-based or does it have the same memory problem? http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/comparison-report-virtualizers
- Would creating multiple JasperPrint objects of sections of the PDF content and then merging them with the exporter into one output stream work?
- Any suggestions?

---